Unknown import symbol in importing root_mean_squared_log_error from sklearn.metrics
I tried to import the function root_mean_squared_log_error from sklearn.metrics like this:
from sklearn.metrics import root_mean_squared_log_error

However, it shows
"root_mean_squared_log_error" is unknown import symbol

My versions of sklearn, python interpreter and Pylance are v1.4.2, v3.12.2 64-bit and v2024.4.1 respectively.
First I checked if this function is explicitly defined by entering the __init__.py file of sklearn.metrics, and I can see it is imported from _regression which contains the definition.
Then I copied all the functions imported from _regression to my own file, like this:
from sklearn.metrics import (
    d2_absolute_error_score,
    d2_pinball_score,
    ...
    r2_score,
    root_mean_squared_error,
    root_mean_squared_log_error,
)

Only the last two ones can not be recognized, which are new in version 1.4. So I am wondering if I am doing something wrong with these functions with the newest version(stable).
Note: My Code works just fine(can be compiled and executed normally), and this error is incurred by Pylance(reportAttributeAccessIssue).
